# Modify Certain Value of csv **JAVASCRIPT && node**

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

Hello i have a csv that i want to get the value of. And modify that value.

Example Lets say that i have this as my csv

CSV
 `90,90,90,90,90 3,1,1000,2,931`

And i want to acess the number "2". How do i acess the value. And then also how do i modify the value.

Meaning i want to acess a value on the csv and modify that same value.

Im expecting the value of the position on the csv and then modify that same position.

Tell me if something is unclear
Thank you for your help!

OS:
windows 11 should also work on linux(rasberrypi sos)

Answer (score 1):

So the CSV is the string `90,90,90,90,90 3,1,1000,2,931`

Let's transform the string into an array of int

```
const arr = csv.split(",").map(e => parseInt(e));
```

Finding the index of the element === 2 will be

```
const index = arr.findIndex(e => e === 2);
console.log(index); // 7
```

Let's change its value

```
arr[index] = 3; // Its value will now be 3
console.log(arr); // [ 90, 90, 90,90, 90, 1,1000, 3, 931 ]
```

Now we re-assign the variable "csv" according to the new modified value

```
csv = arr.join(",")
console.log(csv) // '90,90,90,90,90,1,1000,3,931'
```

Comment: Sorry if i wasnt clear, but i wanted to get from file and then write again to the file such as 90,90,90,90,90    (there should be here a enter here) 3,1,1000,2,931  and then write again as 90,90,90,90,90    (there should be here a enter here) 3,1,1000,41,931

Comment: Hope you understand this

Comment: Here is a better explanation https://github.com/badonyt/badonyt/blob/main/Examples/dellater.md